# Unicode Aware String.split('') without using ES6 or ES5

Tags: javascript, unicode

```
var emoji = '';

var s = emoji.split(''); // ["�", "�"]  String.split('') destroys surrogate pairs.

var s = emoji.splitUnicodeAware(''); // ['']
```

Iterators / ES6 are not allowed, neither is `Array.from`, Regex `/u` flag, `[...spread]` syntax, etc.

Any relevant links are also appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: And why the silly restrictions?

Comment: `Array.from` is ES6, not ES5. Can you really not use ES5 from 2009?

Comment: Whoops. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the input string is well-formed (doesn't contain broken characters to begin with), given that surrogate pairs range from D800 to DBFF (in hex), per [unicode.org](https://www.unicode.org/faq//utf_bom.html), all you need to do is check if a character is within that range to decide whether to capture one character or two:

```js
var emoji = 'foo  IU bar ';
var matches = emoji.match(/[^\uD800-\uDBFF]|[\s\S]{2}/g);
console.log(matches);
```

If you wanted to validate trailing surrogates too, match the trailing character as DC00 to DFFF in hex.

Answer (score 0):

Both these examples work with Firefox 27 (2014) or higher. I would say that is
reasonably portable:

```
const s = '';

// example 1
let a1 = [];
for (let s1 of s) {
   a1.push(s1);
}

// example 2
let a2 = [...s];

// print
console.log(a1, a2);
```

Comment: This requires the use of the array iterator, unfortunately